# How many square foot of coverage per bag of mortar when repointing brick?

Tags: masonry

I haven't been able to find the answer anywhere. In a standard 80lb bag of mortar mix, how many square feet of coverage can I get when repointing a running bond brick wall with standard 8x4x2.25 assuming a depth of about 1"?

Anybody have a rough rule of thumb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had a few minutes... created a model in SketchUp and found that with a 3/8" wide joint the mortar takes up .55 sq ft per square foot of wall. 1" depth after removing part of the old mortar and it comes out to 0.015 cubic feet per square foot of wall.

About 0.7 cubic feet of wet mortar per 80lb bag and that comes out to close to 46 square feet per 80lb bag for a 3/8" wide mortar joint.

With a 1/2" joint width yield is roughly 36 square feet per bag.